# `from foo import *` in Typescript

Tags: import, module, namespaces, typescript

I'm working on a fairly small Typescript codebase that's gotten big enough to be split up across multiple files. It's a blackjack game. I currently have a bunch of code that looks like:

```
var player = new Player();
player.hand = new Hand([new Card(), new Card(), new Card()]);
```

in my main file, `app.ts`. For my sanity, I'd like to split the `Player` class off into one module and the `Hand`  and `Card` off into a second. However, I'd like to keep `Player`, `Card`, and `Hand` all available in the top level scope for two reasons. First, to avoid things like:

```
var player = new Players.Player();
player.hand = new Cards.Hand([new Cards.Card(), new Cards.Card(), new Cards.Card()]);
```

and second, because I think it suggests a hierarchical relationship between `Cards` and `Hand` that I don't want to suggest. `Cards` contains stuff like `Card`, `Deck`, `Hand`, etc -- I think it's the sanest name choice (rather than something like `CardCollections`), but reading `Cards.Hand` makes me feel like `Hand` is-a `Cards`, which it isn't.

In Python, I would write:

```
from Cards import Card, Hand, Deck
from Players import Player
```

or

```
from Cards import *
from Players import *
```

[The Typescript handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-alias) suggests, essentially, that you make aliases for everything you need, but it looks to me like you still can't import anything into the top-level namespace.

Does this exist in Typescript?

Comment: Note that `from Foo import *` is [considered bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/119527) in Python.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware -- I would write the former, but it doesn't make for a clear question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that you make aliases for everything you need, but it looks to me like you still can't import anything into the top-level namespace

Not the global *global* namespace but the top level namespace in a file, you do something like:

```
var Hand = Card.Hand; 
var Player = Players.Player;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to @basarat answer, build your files as CommonJs modules using the `--module commonjs` flag on `tsc` and use the `import...require` syntax

To keep thing simple, have a single file per class

in Player.ts

```
class Player {


}
export = Player
```

in Hand.ts

```
class Hand {


}
export = Hand
```

in app.ts

```
import Hand = require('./Hand')
import Player = require('./Player')

var player = new Player()
```

Please note, no `.ts` extension in `require`

As an added benefit, you get easy access to the whole world of Node JS